# How to add in stock filter to category products collection?

Tags: category, product-collection, stock, collection-filtering

I want to show only products in stock, how to do this with following Magento code?

```
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(55);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category_model);
```

How to add this filter to above code?

Answer (score 4):

Add below code to  filter  the collection

> ```
> $cond = array(
>     '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
>     '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND {{table}}.manage_stock=0',
> );
>
>
>     $cond[] = '{{table}}.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND {{table}}.is_in_stock=1';
>
>
> $collection->joinField(
>     'inventory_in_stock',
>     'cataloginventory/stock_item',
>     'is_in_stock',
>     'product_id=entity_id',
>     '(' . join(') OR (', $cond) . ')'
> );
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection->addStoreFilter()
```

should do the trick, at least if you did not configure Magento to show out of stock products in the frontend. This is filtering the collection to only show products available in the current store.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```